# JAVA Best way to generate a line of " * "

Tags: java

I am currently trying to generate a line of 60 stars
however I found several ways to do it.

```
//Method 1
System.out.println(String.format("%60s", "").replace(' ', '*'));

//Method 2
for(int i=0;i<60;i++)
    System.out.print("*");
System.out.println("");

//Method 3
int i=0;
while(i<60) {
    System.out.print("*");
    i++;
}
```

Which is the best way to approach? (In terms of time and In terms of style)

And if there are any other methods to do this?

```
//Modular Approach, not bad
static String repeat(final String str, final int n) {
    final int len = (str == null) ? 0 : str.length();
    if (len < 1 || n < 1) {
        return "";
    }
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(str);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

System.out.println(repeat("*", 60));
```

And

```
//Similar to method 1
System.out.println(new String(new char[60]).replace("\0", "*"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by best?  Time complexity?

Comment: Have you tried using `System.nanoTime()` to check how long each method takes?

Comment: I'm a newbie in Java, so how do I use System.nanoTime() ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(60).forEach(System.out::print);
System.out.println(); // for the newline at the end
```

Or the slightly hacky, but one line:

```
System.out.println(new String(new char[60]).replace("\0", "*"));
```

The hacky version works because all java arrays of numeric primitives are initialized with the value 0 in all elements, which are each then replaced with the desired character once in a String.

Answer (score 2):

Of the methods presented, the first will likely perform best because it doesn't require a loop and only calls `print` once. But this smells of *premature optimization*. The choice of loop (`for` or `while` or `do-while`) is almost certainly optimized away by the compiler and JIT (depending on platform and version). However, I would prefer a fourth approach. [Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html). In this case, I would build the `String` with a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and then print that. Something like,

```
static String repeat(final String str, final int n) {
    final int len = (str == null) ? 0 : str.length();
    if (len < 1 || n < 1) {
        return "";
    }
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(str);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and then

```
System.out.println(repeat("*", 60));
```

Comment: Nice and Clean! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient? How about:

```
int n=60;
char[] data = new char[60];

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    data[i] = '*';

System.out.print(data);
```

Only one object generated and a single call to "print".

Comment: Agreed! How about `while(--n>=0)` instead of `for`?

Comment: It seems more complicated than method 2

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need the ability to easily modify the number of stars, I'd honestly just use 
`System.out.println("************************************************************");`

Or if you need to use the stars multiple times, which I'd assume is likely,

`String sixtyStars = "************************************************************";`

and then you can just pass `sixtyStars` to whatever printing method you need.

Comment: Haha nice, but i would prefer the stars which can be easily modified :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinions. . I think M1 is better and faster than using loops. However, M2 is easiest way to understand. 
Also you can add M4 by using

```
 PrintStart (60);\\ on call 


  \\function body 
 public static void PrintStart  ( int i){

       if (i==0)
           return; 
      System.out.print ("*");
      PrintStart  (i-1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of time complexity, they are the same: O(n).
However M2=M3 better than M1 (It actually contains loops - you must see the source code of String.format and String.replace).

In terms of space complexity, M.2 is better.

In this problem M.2 is enough, can be improved by using StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

What about using custom [collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)?

```
String result = IntStream.range(0, 60).mapToObj(i -> '*')
        .collect(Collector.of(
                StringBuilder::new,
                StringBuilder::append,
                StringBuilder::append,
                StringBuilder::toString));
```

or the same with joining *Strings*

```
String result = IntStream.range(0, 60).mapToObj(i -> "*")
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Kinda complicated but Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I have used regularly - using Java 8 streams:

```
Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(60).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

For me it captures the intent well: generate a stream of asterisks, get the first 60 and join them together.

Comment: Does this only work in Java 8 or above?